# Server to server SSEs

Tags: server-sent-events

This might be a stupid question but i cant find much info online about it. I would like to know if server sent events can be used between 2 servers. I think in theory this should be possible but everything i read about SSEs is about the client side and the EventSource object.

This is fine but my web API must also be able to stream data to clients that are not web browsers but most likely backend servers/ network apps. Can someone confirm that it can or cannot work and if it can, could you please add some example code of how a backend language would subscribe to it?

Comment: Reading from an event source can be done on the backend or between servers - this Golang repository illustrates how to do so from the backend: https://github.com/r3labs/sse#quick-start . Other resources exist too, such as with NodeJS. It can be achieved in other languages as well - you'll have to write a handler that can process the event stream header and its text data that's produced by SSE.

Comment: Thank you. If you posted it as an answer i would mark it as correct. I realized that different languages have different names for this, some use the same name "EventSource" API, for others its just SSE API or SSE client, etc.

Comment: no prob, and happy to help! Answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reading from an event source (also called a Server Sent Event or SSE) can be done from the backend.** This is an snippet from the [golang repository (r3labs/sse)](https://github.com/r3labs/sse#example-server) that illustrates how to create a backend client that reads from an event stream.

```
func main() {
    client := sse.NewClient("http://server/events")

    client.Subscribe("messages", func(msg *sse.Event) {
        // Got some data!
        fmt.Println(msg.Data)
    })
}
```

It's also possible to do this with [Python](https://github.com/btubbs/sseclient#usage), as well as other frameworks such as NodeJS. On the off-chance that support isn't available in your language of choice, one could implement support by determining how to poll and read from the event stream when the HTTP header `text/event-stream` is present.

REFERENCES

1. [Original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74630054/server-to-server-sses?noredirect=1#comment131879544_74630054)